# so i keep getting this name error in my Tkinter code for a school project and i dont quite understand why

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

**File "main.py", line 47, in calculate
if (i.get() == 1):
NameError: name 'i' is not defined**

thats the error i keep receiving and i dont quite understand why. im mainly a beginner at coding if that helps. help would be greatly appreciated and heres the code. its a currency converter tho its incomplete at the moment because i dont understand what the error is how to fix it

````
#the name of this app is MyFirstGui
class MyFirstGUI:
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master    
    

    #The title
    self.label_a = Label(master, text="~~~ Currency Converter ~~~")
    self.label_a.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)  
    

    #Where you would enter the amount of money
    self.label_b = Label(master, text="Enter Amount of Money (CDN)")
    self.label_b.pack()  
    self.money_entry = Entry(master)
    self.money_entry.pack()    

    i = IntVar()
    #These will make bubble buttons appear that you can check
    rad1 = Radiobutton(master,text='US Dollar', value=1, variable=i)
    rad2 = Radiobutton(master,text='British Pound', value=2, variable=i)
    rad3 = Radiobutton(master,text='Chinese Yuan', value=3, variable=i)
    rad4 = Radiobutton(master,text='Euro', value=4, variable=i)
    rad5 = Radiobutton(master,text='South Korean Won', value=5, variable=i)
    rad6 = Radiobutton(master,text='Mexican Peso', value=6, variable=i)
 
    rad1.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    rad2.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    rad3.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    rad4.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    rad5.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    rad6.pack(pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
    
    self.label_results = Label(master, text="")
    self.label_results.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)  



    #Button to calculate
    self.button_a = Button(master, text="Calculate!", command=self.calculate)
    self.button_a.pack()   
    
  #Where the calculations take place
  def calculate(self):
     if (i.get() == 1):
      canadian_dollars = float(self.money_entry.get())
      us_dollar = (canadian_dollars * 0.75)
      self.label_results.config(text=("$%.2f Canadian Dollars will be equal to $%.2f when converted to US Dollars." % (canadian_dollars, us_dollar)))
    


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: `i` is local variable inside `__init__()` and so cannot be accessed inside `calculate()`.  Change `i` to `self.i` (or better name other than `i`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you do not define the variable i within the function you are using it in (within the calculate function).

If you want to use the same i variable from the one in your **init** function you can either make i an instance variable by using self.i instead of just i, or you can pass i in as a parameter to your calculate function.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response! ive actually not learned about global variables yet. how would i do that if you dont mind explaining?

Comment: Don't use global variables for this application.  Rename `i` in your program to `self.i`, as @Ken suggests.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean global variable, I meant an instance variable. You can use an instance variable by replacing all your 'i' with 'self.i'

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `i` within the initialisation function of `MyFirstGUI` but you're not expanding its scope to include other functions, so `i` is not accessible from the `calculate()` function you've declared later. Without context it's difficult to know what to recommend, but try:

1. Declaring `i` and `root = Tk()` at the top of the script, outside of the `MyFirstGUI` class, if you intend to add more classes that might reference `i`.
2. If `i` will only be used within the context of the first gui class, using `self.i` and `self.i.get()`.
3. Another alternative is to make `i` a global, but this is generally to be strongly discouraged.

If you don't intend to add any more classes that reference `i`, then renaming to `self.i` so that `i` inherits the scope of `MyFirstGUI` would be the most suitable approach.

If you wish to use `i` outside of the scope of a single function (e.g. across both `__init__()` and `calculate()` then I would also strongly encourage you to rename `i` to something more specific.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'         im getting this error by declaring i at the top **Edit:** ive got it to work

Comment: My apologies, it should be below `root = Tk()` as `IntVar()` is a tkinter class which needs a root. Try moving the definition of `i` to below the declaration of `root`. If necessary, you may need to move the declaration of `root` to the top of the script. This is only justifiable if `i` will ever be used outside of `MyFirstGUI` though, and even then it goes against good OOP practice - declaring `i` within the scope of `MyFirstGUI` and letting it inherit `self` is a more sensible approach.

Comment: Glad to hear! Please consider marking the most useful response on this page as an accepted answer to help other people who encounter this post, should they have the same problem.